# Install Ubuntu 12.10 instead of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, partitioning

I have a laptop (4 GB RAM, 500 GB HDD, Intel core i3 2.4 GHz) with 2 Partitions: one For data and one for windows 8 x64.

Actually, I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 instead of Windows 8 but keeping Data partition.

So, my question is: There is no matter to use ubuntu with NTFS Windows Partition. Or i should use ext4 partition for good result? Otherwise what you think about multiple partitions for ubuntu installation?

```
/
/home
/etc
 ...
```

Any suggestion will be very appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Install Ubuntu with the usb/dvd. When you reach the partitioning part,
[image: Ubuntu installation]

choose for "Something else". Then format the Windows 8 x64 partition and select as "/".
After installation, create a shortcut on your desktop to your NTFS partition or add it as a bookmark in Files (Nautilus).